# Why some non-tag badges don't appear in the badge tracking menu?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, badge-tracking

Last times I'm reviewing as much as I can, and I wanted to set tracking on the "Reviewer" badge in my profile. **It isn't in the 'select badge to track' menu though... as well as some other 10 non-tag badges.** Of course I mean on the root site non-meta. (I don't know if the same thing happens on meta).

*Why is that?*

Comment: Perhaps because you only earn the badge from the review queue, and in the review queue the progress is displayed in the upper right corner? (Not sure about the other badges)

Comment: I agree with the reviewing, but what about others? I can understand why there is no tracking for for example "Good Question" or "Stellar Question" because it is not something that is long-term, but some of them are long-term and should be trackable like "Tenacious", "Unsung Hero", etc..

Comment: meta.SO: [Why aren't all the badges shown on the track menu?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263610/why-arent-all-the-badges-shown-on-the-track-menu)

Comment: @Martin: Old habits die hard, eh? It's meta.SE for a long time now... :-)